# End of file in Symfony package for new Laravel project on Homestead

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, homestead

I'm trying to make new Laravel app on my Homestead virtual machine (virtualbox on Win 7 x64).

I'm using this command:
composer create-project laravel/laravel api --prefer-dist

Durning autoload file generation I'm getting end of file error in api\vendor\symfony\console\Input\InputInterface.php
Symphony ver. 2.7.1

This file ends on line 150 (instead of 151) with this contents: 
"    public function set"

I have cleared the composer cache, updated it, but still no luck...
I checked downloaded zip and file in question there appears to be complete...

Please help...I'm running out of ideas...

PS. Sorry for bad English... If you need more info then please post here.

Comment: Have you tried adding an older release to composer (such as Symfony 2.7)?

Comment: I tried, but still same result. Stop in download occurred in different file though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was releated to Homestead on Windows. I switched to xampp on windows and downloaded everything without problem.